# How do you express when a water bottle has turned over and has started leaking?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

When I put a water bottle on the desk, it suddenly fell over and started leaking from the top. How do you express that situation in proper English?

> 1. My water bottle turned over.
> 2. My water bottle fell.

Comment: My water bottle *tipped* over. By the way, bottles don't (usually) have a tap: the part that the liquid pours from is the *mouth.*

Comment: _Fell over_ would also be acceptable.

Comment: *Your 10L water dispenser fell off the table and its tap sprang a leak*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a proper way to express this situation at that moment.  You could say:

"It's going to fall!"

(instead of, "It will fall!")

After it has fallen, you might say:

"My water bottle turned over."  (which implies that it stayed on the desk, and that it somehow became inverted)

"My water bottle fell."  (which is appropriate if the bottle fell off the desk)

"My water bottle fell over."  (which is somewhat similar to the first sentence)

Comment: “My water bottle fell over” is not very similar to “My water bottle turned over”. With _fell over_, it’s a very natural sentence that indicates the bottle is no longer standing upright, but now lying on the table. With _turned over_, it’s a strange sentence that I can’t imagine anyone actually saying of a water bottle on a table, unless it suddenly turned itself around 180° by magic. If the water bottle is in water, it can make more sense, since things bobbing in water do sometimes turn over of their own accord.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  You are basically right.  I am going to change it to "somewhat" similar.